# php global vars with 'sourced' php files

Tags: php, html

I have my web site in html, with php chunks embedded. I define some variables in the main page as

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['myVar']= "something";
?>
```

later I have

```
<?php
echo '<p align="center"><img src="./tempImg.php">';
?>
```

the tempImg php file displays, using the phplot.php lib, a dynamic plot of some data read from the database and in the tempImg.php file I must use the myVar variable. 
I tried using the GLOBALS[], the _SESSION[] but I am not able to share the variable in this way.

thanks for any help

Comment: did you actually `include()` or `require()` the file that contains your var? Did you confirm that it was successfully included?

Answer (score 0):

```
$GLOBALS['myVar']= "something";
echo '<p align="center"><img src="./tempImg.php?myVar=' . $GLOBALS['myVar'] . '">';
```

Or just:

```
$myVar = "something";
echo '<p align="center"><img src="./tempImg.php?myVar=' . $myVar . '">';
```

Then access `$_GET['myVar']` in `tempImg.php`.